# WP7 Listpicker not showing all items

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, listpicker

I have a project that requires binding a list of strings to a listpicker control. When the binding is done (either in Loaded or OnNavigatedTo events), the listpicker opens to show the bound items, but some items are randomly missing (in fullscreen mode). When the listpicker starts closing, the missing items seem to appear. Not sure why this is happening - is it a listpicker bug or am I binding incorrectly?. I am using the November 2011 release of the silverlight toolkit.

PS: The issue does not seem to happen when using a small number of items (say up to 10)

Please use the below code to recreate the issue

Main page XAML

```
        <TextBlock Text="Time of Day" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="TimesOfDayList" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Multiple" FullModeHeader="Time of Day"
                                    ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" ItemsSource="{Binding TimesOfDay}" 
                                    Margin="12,0,12,12">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="24,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
    </Grid>
```

Main page code behind

```
private MainPageViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        TimesOfDayList.SummaryForSelectedItemsDelegate = TimesOfDaySummary;
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }

    private string TimesOfDaySummary(IList items)
    {
        string itemNames = string.Empty;

        if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
        {
            var itemsList = items.Cast<string>().AsQueryable();
            foreach (var item in itemsList)
            {
                if (item != itemsList.Last())
                    itemNames += item + ", ";
                else
                    itemNames += item;
            }
        }

        return itemNames;
    }
```

Viewmodel class

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        TimesOfDay = new List<string>
                          {
                              "12:00 AM",
                              "12:30 AM",
                              "01:00 AM",
                              "01:30 AM",
                              "02:00 AM",
                              "02:30 AM",
                              "03:00 AM",
                              "03:30 AM",
                              "04:00 AM",
                              "04:30 AM",
                              "05:00 AM",
                              "05:30 AM",
                              "06:00 AM",
                              "06:30 AM",
                              "07:00 AM",
                              "07:30 AM",
                              "08:00 AM",
                              "08:30 AM",
                              "09:00 AM",
                              "09:30 AM",
                              "10:00 AM",
                              "10:30 AM",
                              "11:00 AM",
                              "11:30 AM",
                              "12:00 PM",
                              "12:30 PM",
                              "01:00 PM",
                              "01:30 PM",
                              "02:00 PM",
                              "02:30 PM",
                              "03:00 PM",
                              "03:30 PM",
                              "04:00 PM",
                              "04:30 PM",
                              "05:00 PM",
                              "05:30 PM",
                              "06:00 PM",
                              "06:30 PM",
                              "07:00 PM",
                              "07:30 PM",
                              "08:00 PM",
                              "08:30 PM",
                              "09:00 PM",
                              "09:30 PM",
                              "10:00 PM",
                              "10:30 PM",
                              "11:00 PM",
                              "11:30 PM"
                          };
    }

    private List<string> _timesOfDay;
    public List<string> TimesOfDay
    {
        get { return _timesOfDay; }
        set
        {
            if(_timesOfDay != value)
            {
                _timesOfDay = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TimesOfDay");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your code and got the same issue. Just by dropping `Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"` from

```
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="24,0,0,0" />
</DataTemplate>
```

looks like it solves the problem. however is a weird behavior which its source comes from Style property.

I'm gonna try out other possibilities and will let you know if I would find out some other info.

Regards,

Comment: Dropping the style did not resolve the issue for me. Can you please recheck that it worked for you?

Comment: Hi again. I've spent some time trying to figure out what is happening here and I am really surprise. There is no way to fix it. I guess it should be a bug, but can't believe nobody came upon this issue so far.

Comment: It seems like the issue occurs if there are more than 18 items in the listpicker. I have submitted an issue on this at codeplex (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/10662). I too am surprised that no one has faced this issue so far. Anyway, hope that it will be resolved quickly. It has become a show stopper for one of our apps.

Answer (score 1):

I have submitted a patch to the project
http://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=silverlight&DownloadId=375366
described as follows:

There is a race condition when navigating to the full picker page, where the items that had their RotationX property animated to spin them in may have moved off the screen before the UpdateOutOfViewItems delegate is called.

As a result some items can remain with a RotationX of -90.

My solution is to pass in the list of items that were in view to the UpdateOutOfView items when the animations were created, rather than collecting those visible when the delegate is finally run.

http://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=silverlight&DownloadId=375366 is the updated ListPickerPage.xaml.cs file required to fix the bug.